# regular expressions emoticons

Tags: python, nltk

I have data split into fileids. I am trying to go through the data per fileid and search for emoticons `:(` and `:)` as defined by the regex. If an emoticon is found I need to retain the information a) the emoticon was found b) in this fileid. When I run this piece of script and print the emoticon dictionary I get 0 as a value. How is this possible? I am a beginner.

```
emoticon = 0
for fileid in corpus.fileids():
    m = re.search('^(:\(|:\))+$', fileid)
    if m is not None:
        emoticon +=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your regex is working, and that `m` should indeed not be `None`.

```
>>> re.search('^(:\(|:\))+$', ':)').group()
':)'
>>> re.search('^(:\(|:\))+$', ':)').group()
':)'
>>> re.search('^(:\(|:\))+$', ':):(').group()
':):('
>>> re.search('^(:\(|:\))+$', ':)?:(').group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

However, a few things are questionable to me.

- this will only match strings that are 100% emoticons
- is fileid really what you're searching?

Comment: I am using the fileid function in NLTK. Each file contains 1 sentence. So I want to check for emoticons in each file id or sentence. Is this not possible? O and I don't want to check for strings that are only containing emoticons, I'll have to change my regex. Thanks! :)

Comment: I fixed the mistake I made with the fileid.