# Extract emoticons from a text

Tags: python, regex, text-processing, emoticons

I need to extract text emoticons from a text using Python and I've been looking for some solutions to do this but most of them like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283681/regular-expressions-emoticons) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571103/capturing-emoticons-using-regular-expression-in-python) only cover simple emoticons. I need to parse [all of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons).

Currently I'm using a list of emoticons that I iterate for every text that I have process but this is so inefficient. Do you know a better solution? Maybe a Python library that can handle this problem?

Comment: Build a regular expression.

Comment: My concern is that it will take a lot of time to match.

Comment: It might take a lot of time, but that doesn't mean it's slow.

Comment: by all means - do not build regular expression.

Comment: @iced Why not? It is likely to be optimised far better than most of what you could do by hand. Try it and see whether it's fast enough.

Comment: @PeterWood there are better algorythms (see answer) and regexps are wrong solution in 99.83% cases.

Comment: @iced There may be faster algorithms, but the regex might be good enough, and is easy to implement and try out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of most efficient solution is to use [Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) and is nontrivial algorithm designed for this kind of problem. (search of multiple predefined strings in unknown text)

There is package available for this.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ahocorasick/0.9
https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/ahocorasick/

Edit:
There are also more recent packages available (haven tried any of them)
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahocorasick/1.0.0

Extra:
I have made some performance test with [pyahocorasick](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahocorasick/1.0.0) and it is faster than python re when searching for more than  1 word in dict (2 or more).

Here it is code:

```
import re, ahocorasick,random,time

# search N words from dict
N=3

#file from http://norvig.com/big.txt
with open("big.txt","r") as f:
    text = f.read()

words = set(re.findall('[a-z]+', text.lower())) 
search_words = random.sample([w for w in words],N)

A = ahocorasick.Automaton()
for i,w in enumerate(search_words):
    A.add_word(w, (i, w))

A.make_automaton()
#test time for ahocorasic
start = time.time()
print("ah matches",sum(1 for i in A.iter(text))) 
print("aho done in ", time.time() - start)


exp = re.compile('|'.join(search_words))
#test time for re
start = time.time()
m = exp.findall(text)
print("re matches",sum(1 for _ in m))
print("re done in ",time.time()-start)
```

Comment: I've been reading about it and seems efficient enough. I'm going to give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: What pyahocorasick doesn't do is return the start index of the match (just the end). I implemented it my self and is working really well. Thanks again for your answer.